# Rust shadowed variable type auto-change

Tags: rust

I am referring to the type of the `guess` variable. It seems that the type changes from a `String` then to an `i32` and then back to a `String`.

```
use std::{any::Any, io};

fn print_type_of<T>(_: &T) {
    println!("{}", std::any::type_name::<T>())
}

fn main() {
    let mut guess = String::new();

    loop {
        print_type_of(&guess);
        guess.clear();

        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut guess)
            .expect("Failed to read line");

        let guess: i32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
            Ok(x) => x,
            Err(_) => continue,
        };

        print_type_of(&guess);

        if guess == 69 {
            break;
        }
    }

    println!("{}", guess);
}
```

I can understand the concept of *shadowing* in a linear and scoped context. But after the `guess` has been shadowed and becomes an `i32`, I am surprised to find that when going back at the top of the *loop*, it suddenly changes back to a `String` type!?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shadowing does not follow control flow, it is linear with the source code. At the loop entry, you have one `guess` with type `String`. When you declare `let guess: i32`, you introduce a new variable named `guess` with the type `i32`. You cannot access the original `guess` because it is shadowed, but it's still there. We don't "loop again": we just inspect all `guess` variables in the current scope, and the one you're referring to is the closest one. When you are after the second `guess` declaration it's it; when you're before it's the first `guess`. You may find it more natural if you'll think of each variable as having a number attached:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut guess_1 = String::new();

    loop {
        print_type_of(&guess_1);
        guess_1.clear();

        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut guess_1)
            .expect("Failed to read line");

        let guess_2: i32 = match guess_1.trim().parse() {
            Ok(x) => x,
            Err(_) => continue,
        };

        print_type_of(&guess_2);

        if guess_2 == 69 {
            break;
        }
    }

    println!("{}", guess_1);
}
```